# vbscript regex expression matching curly brace

Tags: regex, vbscript

Need to match pattern `abc{23473sdhf}` using regex in vbscript

i have tried following regex pattern but it is not working

```
abc{*}
abc\{*\}
abc\\{*\\}
```

none of the above is working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do is this instead:

```
abc\{.*\}
```

Here the `.*` matches anything that is not a new-line as many times as it can. `*` is not enough.

Ideally, you should be doing it as:

`abc\{[^{]*\}`

Comment: @user3145195. Would you mind accepting my answer if it was helpful? Thank you

Comment: sure i will accept your answer. it says 13 minutes more to accept the answer, after 13 minutes will surely accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
abc\{[^}]+\}
```

explain:

> ***`[^character_group]`*** Negation: Matches any single character that is not in `character_group`

Comment: Thanks Ria for your answer